# Crear índice de un libro con C, a través de un bucle

Tags: c

El bucle sería algo así, como un índice para un libro. En este caso, habría un capítulo, 2 secciones y 3 subsecciones

Lo que quiero que salga es algo así:

```
Seccion 1.1
 Subseccion 1.1.1
 Subseccion 1.1.2
 Subseccion 1.1.3
Seccion 1.2
 Subseccion 1.2.1
 Subseccion 1.2.2
 Subseccion 1.2.3
```

De momento llevo esto habiendo declarado las variables:

```
    do{
    printf( "Capitulo %d\n",c);
    printf (" Seccion %d.%d\n",c,s);
    printf ("  Subseccion %d.%d.%d\n",c,s,sb);
    ++c;
} while ( aqui no se que poner );
```

pero no sé cómo hacer para que la sección y la subsección empiece en 1 y acabe en el número que ponga el usuario al hacer `scanf`.

Comment: Agrega la declaración de variables para saber que son esas cosas en tu codigo.

Comment: `aqui no se que poner` -> `c != Nº iteraciones` y `++c` -> `c++` para sumar uno, aparte de declararlo fuera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes anidar bucles `for` que te permitan imprimir toda la estructura que quieres mostrar sobre tu libro. Para ello anida desde la fuente más grande (capítulo) hasta la más pequeña (subsecciones).

El código que buscas sería algo parecido a esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int c=0, s=0, sb=0;

    printf("Inserte numero de capitulos: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    printf("Inserte numero de secciones: ");
    scanf("%d", &s);
    printf("Inserte numero de subsecciones: ");
    scanf("%d", &sb);

    for (int i=1 ; i<=c ; i++)
    {
        printf( "Capitulo %d\n",i);
        for (int j=1 ; j<=s ; j++)
        {
            printf (" Seccion %d.%d\n",i,j);
            for (int k=1 ; k<=sb ; k++)
            {
                printf ("  Subseccion %d.%d.%d\n",i,j,k);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Como mejora se podría perfeccionar para que no todos los capítulos tuvieran el mismo número de secciones y subsecciones, pero eso ya te lo dejo a ti.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Solo quería agregar, que SI puedes hacerlo usando do-while como propones inicialmente.

Basta con, como se hace en el for, usar un contador y ya.
En este caso, los contadores son x,y,z. Y además tendrían que ser reiniciados una vez terminada la seccion.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int c=0, s=0, sb=0;

    printf("Inserte numero de capitulos: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    printf("Inserte numero de secciones: ");
    scanf("%d", &s);
    printf("Inserte numero de subsecciones: ");
    scanf("%d", &sb);

    int x=1, y=1, z=1;
    
    do{
        printf( "Capitulo %d\n",x);
        do{
            printf (" Seccion %d.%d\n",x,y);
            do{
                printf ("  Subseccion %d.%d.%d\n",x,y,z);
                z++;
            }while(z<=sb);
            z=1;
            y++;
        }while(y<=s);
        y=1;
        x++;
    }while(x<=c);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

```
int main(){
  int s=0, c=0, sc=0;
  printf("Introduzca # capitulos: ");
  scanf("%d", &c);
  printf("Introduzca # secciones: ");
  scanf("%d", &s);
  printf("Introduzca # subsecciones: ");
  scanf("%d", &sc);

  for (i=1; i<=c; i++){
  printf( "Capitulo %d\n",c);
  for (j=1; j<=s; j++){
  printf( "Seccion %d.",c);
  printf( "%d\n",s);
  for (k=1; k<=sc; k++){
 printf( "Subseccion %d.",c);
 printf( "%d.",s);
 printf( "%d\n",sc);
 }}}
```

Comment: Tu código contiene errores, deberías verificarlos. Recuerda que dentro del for, las variables van declaradas: `for(int i =1 ....)`

Comment: _¿Qué hace este código?_ Ten en cuenta que el código debe ser útil no solo para el OP (autor de la pregunta) sino para los demás usuarios de la comunidad: sin explicaciones, es difícil comprender su funcionalidad. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento de [es.so], y luego pulsa en [edit] para editar tu respuesta.

Comment: Usar indentación ayuda a la comprensión. Si pones todo alineado al margen izquierdo hay que esforzarse por encontrar donde termina cada cosa. Y si hay que esforzarse mucho con la pregunta, no será respondida.